# How to get extended user access token of marketing API using restfb

Tags: java, facebook-access-token, restfb, facebook-marketing-api

I have tried getting extended user access token, but this user with following code

```
AccessToken accessToken =
               new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainExtendedAccessToken(MY_APP_ID,
                 MY_APP_SECRET, MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);
```

this access token is having permission for only public profiles, I need an user access token with permission to 
ads_management
ads_read
and I am getting Exception while trying to get adaccounts:

```json
{  
    "error":{  
        "message":"(#10) You do not have sufficient permissions to perform this action",  
        "type":"OAuthException",  
        "code":10,  
        "fbtrace_id":"GG27ChsELJV"  
    }   
}
```

Comment: I think you are trying to extend token with extending permission which is not allowed

Comment: An extended access token is not a access token with extended rights. It an access token with extended lifetime ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We are able to fetch user access token which provides ads_read access by default, if we get MY_ACCESS_TOKEN from admin(page admin).
`AccessToken accessToken =
               new DefaultFacebookClient().obtainExtendedAccessToken(MY_APP_ID,
                 MY_APP_SECRET, MY_ACCESS_TOKEN);`